# Angular JS - providers vs controllers

Tags: angularjs

Why do we need services or factories, we can also do the same thing by making a normal javascript function, or writing the logic in the controller itself.
For example, when i get json data from the server using '$http.get', i can do it by writing a separate service for it but why is it even required when we can directly write its code in the controller?

Comment: read this article would be helpful http://kirkbushell.me/when-to-use-directives-controllers-or-services-in-angular/

Comment: Well every framework is written in a specific language, so obviously you can accomplish everything the framework does without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question to ask for clarification before digging into Angular as understanding the parts will enable you to write good Angular code and not just do something because you can.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKl1Y.jpg
This is a good visual for Angular as an MVC.
The simple answer to your question is that services should be passing information through your controllers to your various pages and routes. All information logic shared across these views belongs in the service. Controllers pass along that information from the view to the service and from it. Information and logic local that view that doesn't need a broader scope can stay in the controller. This is the clean separation that makes Angular a strong framework.

Comment: does MVC architecture also help in faster page loads....since the logic is at different place?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer that helpfully but a good place to start looking for the answer would be this documentation on how angular apps are bootstrapped. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp